# Fetch data from mongodb Array of documents inside document

Tags: mongodb

Trying to write query to fetch specific Items from Items array stored inside document:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"60b72410daa9663308a328ca"},"custId":"1852","Items":[{"centerId":"1234567890","workOrderId":"123456","itemCode":"ABCD12EF","folderParentId":"22","boxId":"7","name":"CenterID_ItemCode_WorkOrderNumber.PDF"},{"centerId":"1234567890","workOrderId":"123456","itemCode":"ABCD12EF","folderParentId":"22","boxId":"2","name":"CenterID_ItemCode_WorkOrderNumber.PDF"},{"centerId":"1234567890","workOrderId":"123456","itemCode":"ABCD12EF","folderParentId":"33","boxId":"3","name":"CenterID_ItemCode_WorkOrderNumber.PDF"},{"centerId":"1234567890","workOrderId":"123456","itemCode":"ABCD12EF","folderParentId":"33","boxId":"3","name":"CenterID_ItemCode_WorkOrderNumber.PDF"},{"centerId":"1234567890","workOrderId":"123456","itemCode":"ABCD12EF","folderParentId":"folderParentId","boxId":"box id","name":"CenterID_ItemCode_WorkOrderNumber.PDF"},{"centerId":"1234567890","workOrderId":"123456","itemCode":"ABCD12EF","folderParentId":"folderParentId","boxId":"box id","name":"CenterID_ItemCode_WorkOrderNumber.PDF"}]}
```

I want to fecth rows with boxid=2;
My query is **{ "custId" : "1852","Items.boxId" : "2"}**
but after this also it gives all items irrespective of boxid.
Note:It's filtering on the basis of custId but not on boxid.

Please let me know where i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use projection

```
db.collection.find({
  custId: "1852",
  "Items": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "boxId": "2"
    }
  }
},
{
  "Items.$": 1
})
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2S-SUtjVoXv)**

Comment: There is one issue with this solution It always return only one element even if it have multiple elements.